# Pandas dataframe group values in the order in which they appear

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

[image: A]

Would like to create a new dataframe that takes the values of A and B and arranges them like this:

[image: B]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create a new column that is essentially a sub-index for each value in `A`.  Then you can sort on the sub-index.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,40],[1,39],[1,73],
                   [2,58],[2,65],[2,22],
                   [3,9],[3,0],[3,21]], columns=list('AB'))

for a in df.A.unique():
    df.loc[df.index[df.A==a],'x'] = list(range(sum(df.A==a)))

df
# returns:
   A   B  x
0  1  40  0
1  1  39  1
2  1  73  2
3  2  58  0
4  2  65  1
5  2  22  2
6  3   9  0
7  3   0  1
8  3  21  2

df.sort_values(by=['x','A'])[['A','B']]
# returns:
   A   B
0  1  40
3  2  58
6  3   9
1  1  39
4  2  65
7  3   0
2  1  73
5  2  22
8  3  21
```

Comment: You can produce the `x` column more easily by doing `df.groupby('A').cumcount()`.

Answer (score 1):

- `groupby` column `'A'` and use `cumcount` to index each grouping separately
- then `argsort` and pass that to `iloc` to reorder accordingly

---

***solution***

```
df.iloc[df.groupby('A').cumcount().argsort()]

   A   B
0  1  40
3  2  58
6  3   9
1  1  39
4  2  65
7  3   0
2  1  73
5  2  22
8  3  21
```